# Check if the message channel is in that category

Tags: python, discord.py

Can someone help me? I'm trying to make a modmail every thing is working fine, user sends a DM, bot creates a channel under "category" and if someone message inside that "category" it will be delivered to the user via DM. However I get this annoying error every time someone replies inside that "category" or user DMs the bot. I'm trying to make a category check to only do something if it's the mod mail category. Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

```
async def on_message(self, message):

if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
# User DM the bot and the bot will make a textchannel under "category" and will send his DMs there. #

if message.channel.category_id == 123456789101112:
     if isinstance(message.channel, discord.TextChannel):
     # Message the user who DMed the bot using the textchannel under "category", your replies will be sent to the user by the bot via DM. #
```

Everything is working, but I'm getting this error every time someone replies inside that textchannel "category" or user DMs the bot

Error:

```
 if message.channel.category_id == 123456789101112:
 AttributeError: 'DMChannel' object has no attribute 'category_id'
```

Comment: You don't need a # to close the comment. You just need one # at the beginning of your comment and the rest of the line will be a comment.

Comment: Yeah I just did it for style here. Haha issue is fixed, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-statement doesn't make much sense, you should first check for the type of the channel and then for it's category and compare it.

```py
async def on_message(message):
    # Checking if the channel is a dm or a text one
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        # do your thing
    elif isinstance(message.channel, discord.TextChannel):
        if message.channel.category is not None:
            if message.channel.category.id == your_id:
                # do your thing
```

Comment: Edited: it's working now. There's no attribute for message.category, so I changed the message.category to message.channel.category_id

Answer (score 0):

You should format your code properly.

Also you can check whether `message.author.id` is your bots id `client.user.id` or a user.

Read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser) for further information.